# Detecting a pattern in a list/array

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

This is rather an algorithmic question.

I have a Java List (sorted) or array that consists of chars (X and Y) and I need to detect a certain pattern of the way the values are ordered.

The List size is fixed (for example 5). The patterns I'd like to detect are the following:

```
XYYYY
XXYYY
XXXYY
XXXXY
XXXXX
```

So X is always followed by only Y's.

Simple String.equals or contains doesn't work, since it's not scalable and is restricted to a known list size.

Comment: So, what is the pattern? At least one X, and the rest of the string is Y?

Comment: Yes, at least one X and all the rest are Y's, and before X there can be only X's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression for this:

```
boolean matches = s.matches("^X+Y*$");
```

This means:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `X+` means one or more consecutive `X`s
- `Y*` means zero or more consecutive `Y`s
- `$` is the end of the string

Alternatively, you can check the string character-wise:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'X') {
  ++i;
}
if (i < s.length()) {
  if (s.charAt(i) != 'Y') {
    return false;
  }
  while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'Y') {
    ++i;
  }
}
return i == s.length();
```

Comment: Gladly! I didn't know about this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to detect the particular pattern.

```
String pattern = "^(X){1,}Y*$";
```

Here's the complete java code,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "XXXXY";
        String pattern = "^(X){1,}Y*$";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
             System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        } else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the matching group around the `X`; `+` is a more concise way to specify that quantifier; you also can use `matches` instead of `find`, since you are looking for a whole string match.